# Hosting multiple WCF services with single certificate

Tags: wcf, iis-7, certificate, hosting, wcf-binding

I have three different WCF services deployed on server separately in there own application directory under "Default WebSites" in IIS. One of the service is deployed by me and two other services are deployed by some other client. There is a single server certificate deployed in IIS to which i have bind my service.

But when i try to access my service form https I get this error in popup:

"**Address Mismatched. 
The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
This problem might indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.**"

Thee web.config file of my service is as following

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfApp.Service">    

    <endpoint address="customer"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
              contract="WCFApp.ICustomerService" />        

    <endpoint address="order"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
              contract="WcfApp.IOrderService" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>
 </services>

 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior >
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="21" maxConcurrentSessions="50" />         
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>   
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Interesting thing is that when I hit the following URL:
https://myserverurl.com/applicationfolder/service.svc?wsdl

to get the wsdl, it runs perfectly and returns me the wsdl description but the original call is not working.

Why am I getting the "Mismatched Address"? Is there need to add host base address? if yes how and where exactly to add it in web.config and is there need to add it in other two wcf services deployed? Is port conflicting with certificate? I am new to wcf please help me resolve this issue?

I am using .net 4.0, IIS 7.0, windows server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message *says* (basically) that the certificate that you are using for your site doesn't match the DNS name that is being used (from the client's browser) to connect to the site.

My guess is that you are implementing virtual hosting; i.e. multiple services with different DNS names that are being served from one IIS instance.  This won't work ... unless you either use a different certificate for each service, or you use a wild-card certificate that matches all of the service DNS names.

Apparently, name-based SSL virtual hosting is not supported by IIS prior to 7.0.  [This article](http://www.hosting.com/support/iis7/configure-ssl-host-headers-in-iis7) describes how to configure it for IIS 7.0.  But note that the names in the respective certificates *must* match the corresponding virtual host names ...

---

Note that the requirement that the hostnames and certificates must match is fundamental to SSL security.  It is what allows the browser / user to know that it is talking to the expected server (based on the DNS name) and not some imposter site.